# Keybinding with more than one Key programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, key, key-bindings, modifiers

The way to bind <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> is

`new KeyBinding( SaveCommand, Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control )`

for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> is

`new KeyBinding( SaveCommand, Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift)`

But, how about <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>H</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>?? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think that you can do that and definitely not using the `KeyBinding` constructor. In fact, I've never seen a keyboard shortcut like that in any program, so I doubt that it's possible... interested to find out otherwise though.

Comment: visual studio opens "solution explorer" on ctrl+w+s

Comment: No it doesn't... it opens that using Ctrl+W, S which is something very different. That is Ctrl+W and then S.

Comment: And to do so: `<KeyBinding Key="W,S" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding OpenSECommand}"/>`